# UIView animation delays

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview

I'm noticing that UIView animations using the UIView class methods seem to more or less put the program on "pause" until they finish.

Is there a way to have an animation start that, for examples, lasts 3 seconds, and while it is animating, other aspects of the program are still running, accepting touch events, etc?

Comment: Those other aspects could be run on another thread (other than the default UI thread), but I would need to see your code to suggest anything else.

Comment: Neither the thread nor run loop is blocked during animation, just touch events. (and only by default)

Comment: Ah, ok. this is probably what I am seeing. So you cannot receive touch events during an animation at all? If one little UIView is doing an alpha fade for a couple seconds, the program will not accept touch events anywhere else on the screen, by design?

Comment: You can if you set the option I mention in my answer below. I don't recall off the top of my head if animation blocks the whole screen or just the view animated, but I wouldn't be surprised either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, UIKit blocks interaction during animation by default. To override, set `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^
 {
     // ...
 } completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

UIKit is not thread safe, so all such animation must occur on the main thread - not on a background thread. To quote from the Apple documentation:

> **Threading**
>
> Considerations Manipulations
> to your application’s user interface
> must occur on the main thread. Thus,
> you should always call the methods of
> the UIView class from code running in
> the main thread of your application.
> The only time this may not be strictly
> necessary is when creating the view
> object itself; but all other
> manipulations should occur on the main
> thread.